# WordPress Check if database field value exists?

Tags: wordpress

I am using the wordpress function

```
update_user_meta($user_ID, 'meta_key', $meta);
```

I want this happen only if the field value is empty. How to check for that!

Example:

```
if database value exists { do nothing } else {update..}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$value = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'meta_key', true); 

if ($value =='')
{
  update_user_meta($user_ID, 'meta_key', $meta);    
}
```